# Best Linux server OS versions to use

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am going to get a VPS/VDS and will be hosting several websites, Some type of chat server (XMPP, Openfire or eJabberd), and possibly a Teamspeak server.

The websites will be mostly PHP based with javascript, and will need a MySQL server for certain ones. The chat server could get popular quickly, and the Teamspeak will have multiple users in multiple channels.

I want the server to be as efficient as possible. The server will have 1GB or RAM and one processor core until absolutely need to expand.

I have looked at Ubuntu, CentOS, and Linux Mint. I've been leaning toward Ubuntu but I have heard that there are problems with it, and that it isn't very efficient.

Comment: There is no best system. Choose between what you like, comfortable with. This question is too broad. I think it should be closed.

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @Navern I disagree. There are pros and cons to each and every operating system. You could simply list them and it would be less opinion based, and even if it was opinion based, sometimes opinions are also okay, because they speak from experience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should an IT department choose a Linux distribution: Technical reasons](http://serverfault.com/questions/461271/how-should-an-it-department-choose-a-linux-distribution-technical-reasons)

Comment: @Core opinions arn't suited for format of serverfault. Here you have one specific question and answer to this question. We have forums for discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those choices, use CentOS.

***Why?***

Mindshare, support, and you won't be the brunt of **Ubuntu** jokes by older sysadmins.

---

It's a contentious debate. And it's full of opinions. I like the stability of Redhat and CentOS. I find Ubuntu to be more accessible and friendly, but fraught with quirks (like [*this*](https://serverfault.com/questions/565183/zfs-on-linux-ubuntu-help-importing-a-zpool-after-ubuntu-upgrade-from-13-04-to-1) or [*this*](https://serverfault.com/questions/567474/how-can-i-install-packages-without-starting-their-associated-services)...) that I don't have the time to work around. Yet, I cannot deny the appeal of Ubuntu to developers and people who have not had to support a lot of physical hardware or consider compatibility in their designs.

See: [How should an IT department choose a standard Linux distribution?](https://serverfault.com/questions/461271/how-should-an-it-department-choose-a-linux-distribution-technical-reasons/461332#461332)

Comment: Since everyone seems to think that this post is counter productive, or a duplicate of the post that you linked, I will mark your answer as correct because it answers my question. Furthermore, I don't see how any of the comments on my original question contribute to this, and if the people answering have any amount of common sense they would post something like this or pros and cons instead of criticizing the question and not taking the time to give me an answer. That is what this site is about, I thought.

Comment: @Core See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. This helps, on one hand, compatibility isn't so much of a problem - as long as I am hosting just what I have built. 
As soon as someone else decides they want to run a separate program on my server, that's where problems begin, weather it be file permissions or network issues, I can run into problems. I suppose to be on the safe side I will go with a Redhat or CentOS install, but may try other ones as well to compare.

Comment: It's also a matter of security, with say, firewalls. Unless they have changed something I'm pretty sure Ubuntu's firewall is less than desirable.